# Initialization of a Fortran parameter with intent(in) argument

Tags: arrays, fortran, initialization, parameter-passing

Consider the following programm :

```
Subroutine foo(p,v)
  implicit none
  integer,                         intent(in)  :: p
  double precision,  dimension(p), intent(in)  :: v 

  !local variables
  integer,parameter :: n=floor(par(p))
  double precision  :: z(2*n)

[...]
End Subroutine
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Array ‘v’ at (1) is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
```

which is quite explicit but I would like to know if there is a way to manage that kind of situation: assign an `intent(in)` argument of the subroutine to a parameter variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zero-length variables to hold intermediate results that can be extracted from them via specification inquiries. Time for an example:

```
module mod_par
   implicit none
   contains
      pure function par(x)
         double precision par
         integer, intent(in) :: x
         par = 1+sqrt(real(1,kind(par))+x)
      end function par
end module mod_par

module mod_foo
!   use mod_par
   implicit none
   double precision par
   contains
      subroutine foo(p,v)
         implicit none
         integer p
         double precision v
         character(0) sv_i(floor(par(p)))
         character(floor(par(p))) sv_j(0)
         logical sv_k(floor(par(p)),0)
         type t
         ! Intentionally empty
         end type t
         type(t) sv_L(floor(par(p)))
         type u(len)
            integer, len :: len
         ! intentionally empty
         end type u
         type(u(floor(par(p)))) sv_m
         double precision z(size(sv_i),len(sv_j),size(sv_k,1),size(sv_L),sv_m%len,0)
!         double precision z(size(sv_i),len(sv_j),size(sv_k,1),size(sv_L),0)
         write(*,*) shape(z)
      end subroutine foo
end module mod_foo

program bar
   use mod_par
   use mod_foo
   implicit none
   call foo(10,1.0d0)
end program bar
```

This fails on both ifort and gfortran because a specification function, here `par`, must be `PURE` and its interface must be explicit. Here `par`, though `PURE` has an implicit interface, so it's rejected. In fact both compilers seem to get confused:

```
specvar.f90:21:25:

          character(floor(par(p))) sv_j(0)
                         1
Error: Function 'par' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

For gfortran, and ifort says

```
specvar.f90(31): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an e
xplicit type.   [PAR]
         type(u(floor(par(p)))) sv_m
----------------------^
```

So we fix this programming error...

```
module mod_par
   implicit none
   contains
      pure function par(x)
         double precision par
         integer, intent(in) :: x
         par = 1+sqrt(real(1,kind(par))+x)
      end function par
end module mod_par

module mod_foo
   use mod_par
   implicit none
!   double precision par
   contains
      subroutine foo(p,v)
         implicit none
         integer p
         double precision v
         character(0) sv_i(floor(par(p)))
         character(floor(par(p))) sv_j(0)
         logical sv_k(floor(par(p)),0)
         type t
         ! Intentionally empty
         end type t
         type(t) sv_L(floor(par(p)))
         type u(len)
            integer, len :: len
         ! intentionally empty
         end type u
         type(u(floor(par(p)))) sv_m
         double precision z(size(sv_i),len(sv_j),size(sv_k,1),size(sv_L),sv_m%len,0)
!         double precision z(size(sv_i),len(sv_j),size(sv_k,1),size(sv_L),0)
         write(*,*) shape(z)
      end subroutine foo
end module mod_foo

program bar
   use mod_par
   use mod_foo
   implicit none
   call foo(10,1.0d0)
end program bar
```

But now gfortran says

```
specvar.f90:32:73:

          double precision z(size(sv_i),len(sv_j),size(sv_k,1),size(sv_L),sv_m%l
en,0)
                                                                         1
Error: Variable 'sv_m' cannot appear in the expression at (1)
```

And ifort:

```
specvar.f90(31): error #6279: A specification expression object must be a dummy
argument, a COMMON block object, or an object accessible through host or use ass
ociation.   [SV_M]
         type(u(floor(par(p)))) sv_m
--------------------------------^
```

So I don't have a sufficiently recent version of either compiler to support type parameter inquiries. Bummer. So we get rid of that last bit...

```
module mod_par
   implicit none
   contains
      pure function par(x)
         double precision par
         integer, intent(in) :: x
         par = 1+sqrt(real(1,kind(par))+x)
      end function par
end module mod_par

module mod_foo
   use mod_par
   implicit none
!   double precision par
   contains
      subroutine foo(p,v)
         implicit none
         integer p
         double precision v
         character(0) sv_i(floor(par(p)))
         character(floor(par(p))) sv_j(0)
         logical sv_k(floor(par(p)),0)
         type t
         ! Intentionally empty
         end type t
         type(t) sv_L(floor(par(p)))
         type u(len)
            integer, len :: len
         ! intentionally empty
         end type u
         type(u(floor(par(p)))) sv_m
!         double precision z(size(sv_i),len(sv_j),size(sv_k,1),size(sv_L),sv_m%len,0)
         double precision z(size(sv_i),len(sv_j),size(sv_k,1),size(sv_L),0)
         write(*,*) shape(z)
      end subroutine foo
end module mod_foo

program bar
   use mod_par
   use mod_foo
   implicit none
   call foo(10,1.0d0)
end program bar
```

And now both compilers produce good code. So you can see that there are many ways to save a temporary integer variable in specifications of zero-length automatic variables that can be used in further specification expressions. Note that if you get too fancy with this kind of syntax you will crash the compiler a lot.

Answer (score 5):

No, that is impossible. A parameter is a *compile-time* constant. Its value cannot come from any argument or variable.

It is also not clear at all why would you want to do that (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ). You do *not* need a parameter to declare an array

```
double precision :: z(2*floor(par(p)))
```

because in *automatic arrays* the bounds can be procedure arguments.

Comment: There is a reason to do that: tell the compiler that some variable which depends on a function parameter is not allowed to be modified once it's set. It's an hint to the compiler, and leads to better programming practices. And, not surprisingly, this [exists in Ada](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/ratl-03-01.html).